# unit test of a simple js arrow function that receives a name and returns a total

Tags: jestjs, arrow-functions

I have to test this simple js function that receives the name of a salesWoman by parameter
and returns the total amount of sales made by said seller:

```
 const salesWoman=(name) =>{
    let salesCounter=0;
    for(let sale of sales){
        if(name== sale[4]){
            for(let salesComponent of sale[6]){
                for(let priceComponent of prices){
                    if(salesComponent == priceComponent [0]){
                        salesCounter+=priceComponent [1]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return `The total amount of sales that ${nombre} made was $${salesCounter}`;
}
```

Now the test i have far is this

```
test ('this function receives a name and returns a total of sales',() => {
    addName("Grace");
    expect (salesWoman('Grace')).toBe(990);
```

Comment: `salesWoman` doesn't return a number, it returns a string. It's unclear where `sales` and `prices` come from and how you would control them in your test environment.

Comment: Where is your `addName` function?